# javascript JSON.stringify() to put array on same line

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am using `JSON.stringify` and I was wondering if there is a way to keep my data on the same line in an array.

I would like it to look like this:

```js
"bob": {
  "college": "UCLA",
  "favorite_color": "green",
  "favorite_numbers": [12, 42]
},
"fred": {
  "college": "USC",
  "favorite_color": "blue",
  "favorite_numbers": [10, 16]
}
```

However it comes out like:

```js
"bob": {
  "college": "UCLA",
  "favorite_color": "green",
  "favorite_numbers": [
    12,
    42
  ]
},
"fred": {
  "college": "USC",
  "favorite_color": "blue",
  "favorite_numbers": [
    10,
    16
  ]
}
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: The way the data is created in the returned string has no bearing on how it will output. You simply parse the string and extract whatever you want in whatever format you want.

Comment: First, that's not valid JSON to start with. Second, how are you using `JSON.stringify` anyway? Because by default it's not formatted. It's just one long (single line) string. Like `{"bob":{"college":"UCLA","favorite_color":"green","favorite_numbers":[12,42]},"fred":{"college":"USC","favorite_color":"blue","favorite_numbers":[10,16]}}`

Comment: If you want to beautify the output string, JSON.stringify is not the library for you.

Comment: @MattBurland The OP is probably using the second and third arguments to `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @AtesGoral: I don't doubt that. *But it's not in the question*.

Comment: docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter

Comment: you can mod the json2.js lib to get a custom working formatter w/o re-inv enting

Comment: This is something I had also felt the need for (for human-readable JSON), but couldn't find a customizable JSON serializer (was in the process of writing one myself, but then got sidetracked). Unfortunately, you're probably on your own (unless there's customizable JSON serializer that I couldn't find at the time). You might have to write your own serializer (or customize and existing implementation as others suggested.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `replacer` parameter:

```js
var obj = {
  "bob": {
    "college": "UCLA",
    "favorite_color": "green",
    "favorite_numbers": [12, 42]
  },
  "fred": {
    "college": "USC",
    "favorite_color": "blue",
    "favorite_numbers": [10, 16]
  }
};

console.log('This is what you really want:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, function(a, b) {
  return (Object.prototype.toString.call(b) === '[object Array]') ? JSON.stringify(b) : b;
}, 4));

console.log('This is your result:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
```

Docs here: [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: The string `"[10,16]"` is not the same as the array `[10,16]`